# Possible to disable automatically sorted for FULLTEXT search?

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

MySQL said: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-natural-language.html

```
SELECT * FROM articles
WHERE MATCH (title,body)
AGAINST ('database' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE);
```

> When MATCH() is used in a WHERE clause, as in the example shown earlier, **the rows returned are automatically sorted with the highest relevance first**. Relevance values are nonnegative floating-point numbers. Zero relevance means no similarity. Relevance is computed based on the number of words in the row, the number of unique words in that row, the total number of words in the collection, and the number of documents (rows) that contain a particular word.

Its possible to disable this "automatically sorted with the highest relevance"? I not need any automatically sorted and want little more perfomance in my query. :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can turn off the sorting.  I suspect that the sorting is only a small part of the cost.  I assume you are using InnoDB's FT, not MyISAM's.  InnoDB seems to be faster.

You understand that when you mix FT and other types of INDEXes, the FT part of the WHERE will happen first.